# Table adapter with visual studio Final Code 

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tableadapter

I enter values in User Name and Password in two text boxes. When I click submit, I want the table adapter to check the database to see if those are really the values and allow the user to log in.

This is my code:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //assign text from the textboxes to variables 
    string userName = TextBox1.Text;
    string passWord = TextBox2.Text;

    lblError.Visible = true;

    try
    {

        string passwordValue = Encrypt(passWord);

        DataSet1.tblUserDataTable dataTable = proccessedProcess.Login(userName, passwordValue);

        if (dataTable != null & dataTable.Count!=0)
        {
            DataSet1.tblUserRow dataRow = dataTable[0];
            if (dataRow.nUserID.ToString() == "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
            {
                lblError.Text = "";

            }

            else if(dataRow.nUserID.ToString() != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
            {
                Session["CurrentUserID"] = dataRow.nUserID.ToString();
                Session["LoggedIn"] = "YES";
                Session["LastLogin"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                Session["UserName"] = dataRow.txtUserName;

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("MainCustomer.aspx");

            }
        } else {


                lblError.Text = "Incorrect UserID or Password";

            }

    }

    catch (Exception E)
    {
        E.Message.ToString();
        lblError.Text = E.Message;

    }


}
```

Comment: why are you doing dataTable[2]? it should be dataTable[0]

Comment: when i changed it to dataTable[0]  and run it, it didn't do anything but the label displayed the text "error"..why is this so?

Comment: Thats because your if condition is wrong. you are doing datarow.nuserid.tostring()!="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". Instead you should do datarow.nuserid.tostring()=="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". You should do equal to equal.

Comment: it says that "There is no row at position 0." with dataTable[0]

Comment: I guess you messed up your code again. Update your code in your question

Comment: i did the == and that worked...thanks..it does the real logins and goes to the next page

Answer (score 1):

in the catch section you have E.Message.ToString(); which has no effect. Either you have to set it to a label inorder to see if there is an exception happening or throw E

```
catch (Exception E)
{
   // E.Message.ToString();
   Throw;
}
```

Comment: It seems correct other than nUserID. what is it? a GUID?. Regardless of that you should either be redirected to default.aspx or Maincustomer.aspx. If you dont, then there is an exception happening. You need to find what it is then fix

Comment: the error is still Object reference not set to an instance of an object. >>>> int i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoginCount"].ToString());
        string UserType = "";

Comment: I don't see Session["LoginCount"] in your code. Paste the whole code in order to assist you in the right direction.

Comment: I still don't see it. Are you sure you included the line that has Session["LoginCount"]

Comment: no i took that one one...now the error with the above code is "There is no row at position 2."